# Vertically center image in JQM ListView with INPUT

Tags: css, listview, jquery-mobile, checkbox

i have a JQM ListView vwith a checkbox inside, and i'm not able to vertically center an image to the left of the text:

```
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Object collector</li>
        <li data-icon="false">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2b" id="checkbox-2b" />
                <label for="checkbox-2b">
                    <img src="/img/image.png"/>
                    <h3>Long description</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ullamcorper, augue a consequat viverra, mi mi varius dui, nec ullamcorper velit eros in quam. </p>
                </label>
            </fieldset>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is a sample of what i mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/BPGre/

here is another try with a div wrapper around the "img" tag but nothing, the image is always aligned to the top:
http://jsfiddle.net/BPGre/1/

I tried some other solutions found at SO, but none of them works because of the INPUT tag inside the ListView item.
Any help are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the image and description wrapper in a table will vertically center it. Using a table probably isn't the most ideal solution but it gets the job done.

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>
         <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
       </td>
       <td>
         <div class="description-wrapper">
           <h3>Collector</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit </p>
         </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BPGre/2/

Comment: wrapping in a table will break the jqm responsive layout, e.g. at smaller screen sizes the text goes positioned under the picture.

Comment: I know. I avoid tables whenever possible. How small of a screen are you developing for? As long as you have the height and width of your image set then you shouldn't have that issue.

Comment: There shall be three resolutions: desktop,tablet, phone. So i would keep the jqm built-in capability to adapt the layout to the screen width. This is the reason because i try to avoid tables layout.